# Reflected XSS in multiline script block

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, reflected-xss

I am trying to exploit a reflected cross site scripting in a GET request where the reflection is in the first multi line script block.

It seems I can use every character but `<`, `>` and `"` and the best payload I could come up with is 
`/?search='}]%3Balert(1)%3B%2F%2F`

And it gets reflected like this:

`<head><script>
  dataLayer = [{
    'pageType': 'Page',
    'category': 'Search',
    'searchTerm': ''}];alert(1);//',
    'searchResults': '0',
  }];
</script>`

Unfortunately this does not work. Neither does it with /* instead of // to comment out the rest of the script block. Is there any way to make it work without using "<" and ">"? Now it fails with "SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'"

Comment: if needed, you can append the payload with code to re-open a new object in an array: `[{` to balance it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to comment anything out.

Use:

```
/?search='-alert()-'
```

JS will attempt to create the search term string from the expression `'' - alert() - ''` which will trigger the `alert` function. I preferred `-` over `+` because it avoids potential issues with URL encoding and is rarely blacklisted, but you may also use any other binary operators to squeeze in your payload without causing a syntax error.

Comment: That actually worked. And this would work in many more cases I assume... :-)
I just wasn't aware that you can squeeze the code in the middle of some string using binary operators.
Thank you Arminius